# Spring security context using cookie

Tags: spring-security

I need to use the cookies instead of httpsession with spring security. Does anyone has idea that this is possible? If it is so pleas send me some resource.

Exactly what i want to do is make a web application stateless.

thanks
Rosh

Answer (score 1):

http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-security-stateless-cookie-based.html might get you started on what you want.

Comment: Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).